# WPF Application Framework (WAF) Tutorial Links/Quick start video links

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworks, waf-framework-c#

I was wondering if there are any quick start (From scratch of a simple application using WAF Framework) is available and preferably a video tutorial. No where in the internet, I could find any tutorial on WAF I am afraid.

Could someone please help me with a video or detailed code project link or any other things for learning this real quick?

I am unable to do a quick start on this as I do not know how to use this download from the codeplex website

http://waf.codeplex.com/

Sad thing is, no video tutorials available in internet as per my research.

Answer (score 2):

I found it helpful to follow [Thomas Romstöck](http://web.archive.org/web/20160529183711/http://codetron.net/author/tom/)'s '[Getting Started with the WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://web.archive.org/web/20160824072341/http://codetron.net/getting-started-with-the-wpf-application-framework-waf/)'.

This will help you to set up the solution and import the WAF NuGet package and create '*Presentation*' and '*Applications*' projects containing the minimum folders:

[image: Solution structure]

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple start would be to use the WAF project template for Visual Studio: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/f8d578d5-cf37-461c-882e-d6e4ca39969b

Just create a new WAF Application and have a look at the code. Otherwise, I believe the best start would be to study the sample applications that comes with the WAF source code.